# How to load data these variable in loop

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

How can I create this part of (JTable) code in loop?

```
Object[][] dataEntries = 
{ 
        { firstName[0], "secondName[0]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[1], "secondName[1]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[2], "secondName[2]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[3], "secondName[3]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) }
};
```

Becouse I want to to this like

```
Object[][] dataEntries = 
{ 
        { firstName[i], "secondName[i]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[i+1], "secondName[i+1]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[i+2], "secondName[i+2]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) },
        { firstName[i+3], "secondName[i+3]", ""Click to select"", new Boolean(false) }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this :

```
Object[][] dataEntries = new Object[4][4];

for(int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++){

    dataEntries[i][0] = firstName[i];
    dataEntries[i][1] = "secondName["+i+"]";
    dataEntries[i][2] = "Click to select";
    dataEntries[i][3] = new Boolean(false);

}
```

Comment: You forgot to create 2nd dimensional array.

Comment: @NarendraPathai thanks for reply but I didnt forgot that : `Object[][] dataEntries = new Object[4][4];`

Comment: Thank you but I change
dataEntries[i][1] = "secondName["+i+"]";
to 
secondName[i]; , becouse it it enough.